# Missing cluster in k-means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to analyse a dataset with the k-means algorithm in python with scikit-learn.

Has anyone ever had the problem of getting less clusters than requested?

With the input

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
```

my samples are only in cluster 0, 1 and 2. Cluster 3 never appears.

Doesn't the algorithm recognise that it could take any sample as new cluster(-center) when there is an empty cluster in the end?

Answer (score 1):

In the k-means algorithm, you start with k centers (which can be chosen by many initialization methods) and define the clusters with respect to the distance to the centers (each point is assigned to the cluster associated to the closest center). Then you re-calculate the centers of each cluster and repeat this procedure until convergence.

If you can't get a clustering with a certain number of clusters, it means the algorithm converges very slowly with this number of clusters and so it tries a smaller number of clusters for practical purposes.

However, it can be proved that the k-means algorithm always converges after a finite number of steps. Notice that in `sklearn`, the declaration of the class you are interested in is like the following :

```
class sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, *, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, algorithm='lloyd')
```

You can try to increase the `max_iter` parameter to see if you get convergence with four clusters for your data.